# Vertical align text with images within a table for E-mail Signature?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, signature

Im creating an E-mail signature with CSS and I'm having a problem getting the text vertical aligned next to a simple image.

Ive tried both valign and Vetical-align, yet none of both works.
Who can help out?

I've made a quick roundup of whats inside my code at the moment.

http://jsfiddle.net/J5LTw/1/

or just in code:

```
<table style="width:500px; font-family:century gothic; font-size:10">
<tr><td><p style="color: #184d95; font-weight:bold">Company</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/xauvbp/5.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20"> Phone</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2d2f6kx.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20"><a href="mailto:info@mail.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none">Mail</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/2j4ebg5.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20"> <a href="http://site.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none">Site</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Apparantly both of below solutions did solve my problem. However, the vertical alignment solution worked, but had to be placed on the <a>. I wasn't satisfied enough and tweaked a little; Removing the V.alignment off the image and adding it to the <a>

Now its perfectly aligned.

Still, as mentioned: You gave the solution to point me in the correct direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/J5LTw/2/

if you `MAKE CLASS` please use this css

```
table tr img{
    height:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

if you write `INLINE CSS` please use

http://jsfiddle.net/J5LTw/3/

```
<table style="width:500px; font-family:century gothic; font-size:10">
<tr><td><p style="color: #184d95; font-weight:bold">Company</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/xauvbp/5.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle;"> Phone</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2d2f6kx.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20"  style="vertical-align:middle;"> <a href="mailto:info@mail.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none">Mail</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/2j4ebg5.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20"  style="vertical-align:middle;"> <a href="http://mennescreative.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none">Site</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Must be inline css, however

I understand you thus mean <img src="x" vertical-align:middle;>
will try.

Comment: I currently have:
    <tr><td><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2d2f6kx.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20" vertical-align="middle"> <a href="mailto:info@mail.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none">Mail</a></td></tr>

But that doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 3):

Hi test with this code :

```
<table style="width:500px; font-family:century gothic; font-size:10">
<tr><td><p style="color: #184d95; font-weight:bold; height:20px; vertical-align:middle;">Company</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/xauvbp/5.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;Phone</td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2d2f6kx.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a href="mailto:info@mail.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none; height:20px; vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;Mail</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/2j4ebg5.jpg" border="0" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a href="http://site.nl" style="color:black; text-decoration:none; height:20px; vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;Site</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool, can u mark this solution is solved your problem please, or vote for her !